# Custom CTreeCtrl - How to modify text / selection color

Tags: mfc, colors, selection, background-color, win32gui

First of all, i would customize - among other things - color of text and selection color(text background).
For example, text color should be blue;  color of text background should be transparent.
So, I have overriden OnPaint() method;
I call SetTextColor() and SetBkColor() functions, but unfortunately I always get invalid colors, or I get an annoying "infinite loop flash" effect.
Here you can see his complete implementation.

```
void CustomTree::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);

    CDC memDC;
    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);

    CRect rcClip, rcClient;
    dc.GetClipBox( &rcClip );
    GetClientRect(&rcClient);

    CBitmap bitmap;
    bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap( &dc, rcClient.Width(), rcClient.Height() );
    memDC.SelectObject( &bitmap );

    CRgn rgn;
    rgn.CreateRectRgnIndirect( &rcClip );
    memDC.SelectClipRgn(&rgn);
    rgn.DeleteObject();

    /* WHAT IS the correct usage of SetText/Bk Color? */

    // ::SetTextColor(memDC, RGB(0, 0, 255));
    // ::SetBkColor(memDC, RGB(0, 0, 255));
    // COLORREF col = SetTextColor(RGB(0,0,255));
    // COLORREF co2 = memDC.SetTextColor(RGB(0,0,255));

    // First let the control do its default drawing.

    CWnd::DefWindowProc(WM_PAINT, (WPARAM)memDC.m_hDC, 0);

    // do some others stuffs...

    dc.BitBlt(rcClip.left, rcClip.top, rcClip.Width(), rcClip.Height(), &memDC, 
                rcClip.left, rcClip.top, SRCCOPY);

    memDC.DeleteDC();
}
```

Where is the error?

Thanks

IT

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change color and font for a treeview, you have to catch and respond to [NM_CUSTOMDRAW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Simply setting the properties before calling the default is insufficient.